# CASE WHEN used twice with nested statement

Tags: sql

I am an accidental DBA and trying to teach myself SQL. I have the following line that returns either a 0 (for NO) or -1 (for YES). On order to see the right field, I nested a query in the line, but not sure how to add the additional Yes/No in place of the 0/-1 results.

```
CASE WHEN lvl >=1 
     THEN A.UserFlag 
     ELSE (SELECT V.UserFlag 
           FROM vt_Asset V 
           WHERE V.ControlNumber=A.ControlNumber
           AND V.lvl=1) 
     END as [Actionable]
```

The results display either 0 or -1 and I want that to display as YES for -1 and NO for 0

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format. Also tag the DBMS you're using.

Answer (score 1):

You could write something like this:

```
(CASE WHEN lvl >= 1 AND A.UserFlag = 1 THEN 'Yes'
      WHEN lvl >= 1 AND A.UserFlag = 0 THEN 'NO'
      ELSE (SELECT (CASE V.UserFlag WHEN 0 THEN 'No' ELSE 'YES' END) 
            FROM vt_Asset V
            WHERE V.ControlNumber = A.ControlNumber and V.lvl = 1
           )
 END) as [Actionable]
```

Comment: Thank you. That works perfectly. I appreciate the assist!

Answer (score 0):

I would probably nest my result and adjust in an outer query,

```
select
        case Actionable
        when 0 then 'NO'
        when -1 then 'YES'
        end as Actionable
...
from (select 
    CASE WHEN lvl >=1 
         THEN A.UserFlag 
         ELSE (SELECT V.UserFlag 
               FROM vt_Asset V 
               WHERE V.ControlNumber=A.ControlNumber
               AND V.lvl=1) 
          END as [Actionable]
    from ...
) as T
```